# How to work out the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ ?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, computational-complexity

Suppose A is a matrix over some ring R (might be non-commutative). How to work out the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A$ as a homomorphism of a free $R$-module. If this homomorphism is invertible, then you can build $A^{-1}$ which is a matrix of the inverse homomorphism.

Comment: How is this different from just restating the question?

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: Of course, it is simply translation into the language of homomorphisms. I think OP ask just this.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be so lucky that $R$ is commutative, then iff the determinant of $A$ is invertible in $R$, you can take the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) and multiply it with the inverse of the determinant squared, see the section named "inverse". This might be possible to apply to some matrices over some non-commutative rings too, I have little experience with those.